# How to use image CDN with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to develop a simple full screen image view in SwiftUI, the image should fit in side the screen, also I want to fetch the image from a CDN so in the request I need to provide the size of the required image.

All the example of SwiffUI I see on the net are some like this.

```
var body: some View {
    Image("my-image")
    .frame(width: 375.0, height: 812.0)
}
```

So I have two question.

1. How do I fetch image from URL/link
2. How do I get the size of the image to request, as it will be different for different iOS devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do I fetch image from URL/link?**

SwiftUI's **Image** component doesn't provide a native way to load image from an URL, suggest you use one of the open source libraries instead of implementing complex image loading logic, I recommend using SwiftUI version popular open source library SDWebImage, it is called [SDWebImageSwiftUI](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI)

Here is an example to load an image from image URL

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    WebImage(url:URL(string: "https://<replace with image URL/link>"))
      .resizable()
      .placeholder {
        Rectangle().foregroundColor(.gray)
      }
    .indicator(.activity)
    .scaledToFit()
    .frame(width: 375.0, height:812.0)
  } 
}
```

**How do I get the size of the image to request, as it will be different for different iOS devices?**

To get the run-time size of a view, SwiftUI provides a container view called [GeometryReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader). Whichever component's size you need you have to embed that component(s) inside a GeometryReader container, this container give you access to the run-time size of itself.

Here is complete code to get the run-time size of an image, make a request to image CDN and load the image into full screen view. Here I am using image from imageOpt [image CDN](https://imageOpt.com) you can use any image CDN.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  // Use the URL of imageSet obtained from image CDN
  let imageURL = "https://djy8xy980kp8s.cloudfront.net/2e0d6k-p25/q"

  var body: some View {
    /* Embed the WebImage component inside a GoemetryReader container
     * this will give you access to run-time size of the container */
    GeometryReader { geo in
      WebImage(url:
        /* Get the final URL with width & height parameters, 
         * since you want to fit the image inside full screen 
         * set crop to false */
         imageOptClient.constructURL(imageURL: self.imageURL, 
           imageSize: CGSize(
             // goe.size will give the runtime size of the container
             width: geo.size.width, 
             height: geo.size.height), 
           crop: false))
      .resizable()
      .placeholder {
          Rectangle().foregroundColor(.gray)
      }
      .indicator(.activity) // Activity Indicator
      .scaledToFit()
      .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height, 
        alignment: .center)
    }
  }
}
```

disclaimer: I work for [imageOpt](https://imageopt.com)

Comment: Thank you @oxi, this is exactly what I was looking for.